# Network discovery programmatically

Tags: java, network-programming

Is there a specific protocol used for network discovery?
I'm looking to code this into an existing java project.  Currently I'm using a port scanner to handle the case, but I'm looking to swap that out for something that can give me a little more info.  If possible I'd like to scan to discover machine and pull the Ip addr, host name, MAC addr, NIC make/model, OS, and anything else I can get.

Comment: Network discovery of what? What machines the host computer is connected to? Other machines running a certain server program? Can you be more specific?

Comment: With a topological map? this will prove a very interesting task...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no one protocol that will do all this for you. I've had to do exactly this and basically, the best approach involves using a combination of heuristics to locate, analyze and cross-reference network nodes and topology. Here are the data sources I used:

- **Traceroute** allows you to identify edge devices and routers in the network
- **Port-scanner** allows you to identify what services are running on each node
- **SNMP** allows you to detect the type of device, as well as all its network interfaces, other IP addresses, the IP of devices connected to each port on switches, the routing table, the process table, the network configuration, etc... This is the best source of data, but requires the node to be running an snmp server (installed by default on windows and most linux distros) and to have credentials.
- **WMI** for windows hosts, will provide roughly the same info as SNMP

[**Here**](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cnrg/topology_aware/topology/topology.html#subnet%20guessing)'s an accademic resource I dug up while working on my topology mapper. Hopefully it will help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Check `nmap` for what it can. It is network scanner, can scan with ARP, TCP-SYN, and many other sniffing techniques. It also contains large database of different machines fingerprints, so it can guess what OS/version given system runs.

Comment: yes, im familiar with nmap.  One of the features I'm looking to get more info to implement is determining MAC addr from the scan.  Any ideas on where to start?

Comment: @Nick I think the easiest way to determine MAC is to do ARP (Address Resolution Protocol) scan (check `arping` utility), or simply try to `ping` address and check ARP table of your system. Keep in mind that you can only get MAC addres of hosts in your local network (or only 1 segment).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNMP) protocol.  It has a way to autodiscover devices on the network.  Keep in mind that there are some security concerns with this (especially older versions of the protocol).

Comment: that's certainly one piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

WBEM (similar to WMI on Windows) can be used to scan Unix computers and other devices. Of course, only if the WBEM instrumentation is installed...

WBEM even works for ESX(i) servers if it is enabled there.

Otherwise you might also use SSH to programatically logon to Unix computers and issue system commands to extract the information you need.

There is a nice Java library for WBEM called [SBLIM](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/sblim/index.php?title=Main_Page) 
There are many Java library for telnet and SSH out there